# Oracle SQL - Easiest way to produce a row of answers in one query, so I don't have to run the query multiple times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple query:

```
Select 
To_Date('2012-sep-03','yyyy-mon-dd')as Date_Of_Concern,
Count(Player_Id) as Retained
From Player
Where
(To_Date('2012-sep-03','yyyy-mon-dd')-Trunc(Init_Dtime))<=7
```

Which Results In:

```
Date_Of_Concern         Retained
 03-Sep-12               81319
```

This query counts all of the players in my database who have logged in(init_dtime) within 7 days of a specific date.

As it stands, I will have to run this query multiple times, for every "Day of Concern" that I wish to know about. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run this query for multiple dates, you would need some mean to hold more than one value. I suggest you use a [`NESTED TABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i46449) object:

```
CREATE TYPE my_dates AS TABLE OF DATE;
/

SELECT d.column_value AS Date_Of_Concern, count(Player_Id) AS Retained
  FROM Player
  JOIN TABLE (my_dates(to_date('2012-sep-03', 'yyyy-mon-dd'),
                       to_date('2012-sep-04', 'yyyy-mon-dd'),
                       to_date('2012-sep-05', 'yyyy-mon-dd'))) d
          ON d.column_value - trunc(Init_Dtime) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
 GROUP BY d.column_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `GROUP BY` to get the count by day:

```
Select 
To_Date(Init_Dtime,'yyyy-mon-dd') as Date_Of_Concern,
Count(Player_Id) as Retained
From Player
Where
(To_Date('2012-sep-03','yyyy-mon-dd') - Trunc(Init_Dtime)) <= 7
GROUP BY To_Date(Init_Dtime,'yyyy-mon-dd')
ORDER BY To_Date(Init_Dtime,'yyyy-mon-dd')
```

Comment: Sean, that's not the question I had. There is only 1 row of results each time I run the above query. The question I had was in regards to finding a way so that I didn't have to run the query each and every day that I wanted to see the result for...if instead I could group them into one big query.

Comment: @Stuav, I don't think you have actually tried Sean's query. It should return results for the range of 7 dates ending on 3-Sep-2012. If you wanted the last seven days from today, use `SYSDATE` instead of `To_Date('2012-sep-03','yyyy-mon-dd')`.

Answer (score 0):

> within 7 days of a specific date

To be able to do what you want you will have to know what "specific date" you are talking about by either a formula or a date range. Any random date would obviously require the user to either enter that date or modify the query to run for that date (the way you mentioned).

Comment: The problem is the "init_dtime" (aka the last date the person logged in) gets over written each time someone logs in). So if a person was active on June 1, 2012 and then logs in again on Aug 12,2012, the only init_time that is left is Aug,12,2012

Comment: @Stuav isn't it how this is supposed to be? I still don't see `init_dtime` as an issue rather your comparison date i.e. 2012-sep-03 in your query may change as per your need or as per reporting need. If the user was last active on `12-AUG-12` then a comparison of `THE_DATE - '12-AUG-12 <= 7` may or may not return true based on `THE_DATE`. But, if I understand correctly, your problem is `THE_DATE`!!

Comment: So I have to incorporate The_date somehow..can you be a little more specific?

Comment: What ever solution it is you would still need to enter `THE_DATE` because its not specific (for example something like `sysdate-15`) you need to be sure of what `THE_DATE` could be otherwise there is no other way rather than manually entering or changing the date in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but this is probably what you want. Might have suboptimal performance though.

```
12:32:22 HR@vm_xe> l                                                                        
  1   with player(id, dt) as (                                                              
  2     select 1, date '2012-01-01' from dual union all                                     
  3     select 2, date '2012-01-01' from dual union all                                     
  4     select 3, date '2012-01-02' from dual union all                                     
  5     select 4, date '2012-01-03' from dual union all                                     
  6     select 5, date '2012-01-04' from dual union all                                     
  7     select 6, date '2012-01-05' from dual union all                                     
  8     select 7, date '2012-01-06' from dual union all                                     
  9     select 8, date '2012-01-07' from dual union all                                     
 10     select 9, date '2012-01-08' from dual union all                                     
 11     select 10, date '2012-01-09' from dual union all                                    
 12     select 11, date '2012-01-10' from dual                                              
 13   )                                                                                     
 14     select distinct                                                                     
 15            to_char(dt, 'dd-mm-yyyy') dt                                                 
 16            ,count(*) over (order by trunc(dt) range interval '7' day preceding) week_cnt
 17       from player                                                                       
 18*     order by 1, 2                                                                      
12:32:22 HR@vm_xe> /                                                                        

DT           WEEK_CNT                                                                       
---------- ----------                                                                       
01-01-2012          2                                                                       
02-01-2012          3                                                                       
03-01-2012          4                                                                       
04-01-2012          5                                                                       
05-01-2012          6                                                                       
06-01-2012          7                                                                       
07-01-2012          8                                                                       
08-01-2012          9                                                                       
09-01-2012          8                                                                       
10-01-2012          8                                                                       

10 rows selected.                                                                           

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

p.s. do not code like

```
(To_Date('2012-sep-03','yyyy-mon-dd')-Trunc(Init_Dtime))<=7
```

code like

```
init_time between to_date('2012-SEP-03', 'yyyy-mon-dd') and to_date('2012-SEP-03', 'yyyy-mon-dd') + 7
```

Unless you don't care about indexes, of course :)